# One-Shot Timer in C++ on WinCE

Tags: c++, timer, windows-ce, scheduling

I'm writing an event handling function, `f(d)`, which receives some data, `d`, and must take take an action `X(d)`, then sleep for 100ms, then take another action `Y(d)`. I would implement it as:

```
void f(d)
{
  X(d);
  Sleep(100);
  Y(d);
}
```

However, `f(d)` is called from a single-threaded event handler, so the Sleep(100) is unacceptable.

I would like to do the following:

```
void f(d)
{
  X(d);
  ScheduleOneShotTimer(Y,d,100);
}
```

I could implement `ScheduleOneShotTimer` by creating a new thread for each call, passing the data as the thread parameter, and calling `Sleep` before executing `Y(d)`. However, as this event may occur up to 100 times per second, I'm concerned about the overhead involved with creating a destroying all those threads.

Preferably there would be operating system level support for a "one-shot timer", but I don't think this is the case on CE. I know about SetTimer, but that is not applicable to me because I am writing a "Console Application" that has no message loop.

Any other suggestions for how to structure this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the [`timeSetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448195.aspx) API (a completely non-intuitive API name, I know).  Use a callback function and the `TIME_ONESHOT` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Great little API. But it turned out all I needed was to batch my X calls, then sleep 100ms, then execute the Ys as a batch. (Also, I am concerned about the resource overhead of the timeSetEvent API: does it create new threads for each event? If not, how does it handle blocking or sleeping within those events? I wish there was more documentation available.)

Comment: It's driven by timer interrupts. I believe a separate thread is spawned for each callback, though it would be easy enough to test.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create one thread that would keep a queue of timestamp-callback pairs, sleep for 100ms (or something smaller) and then execute all elapsed callbacks.
OFC with all inter-thread synchronization (interlocking on a critical section, etc).

It's a performance-conscious solution, not a precision-oriented one. As callbacks pile up, it may take longer than exactly 100ms to execute. But since you're measuring time with Wait (which is not precise) I guess it may be good enough.